Who were Mersenne's counterparts?
Prior to the appearance of scientific journals in Europe, Marin Mersenne played a central role in the dissemination of the works of many of the key intellectuals active in the first half of the seventeenth century.
Wikipedia describes Mersenne as :

[...] the center of the world of science and mathematics during the first half of the 1600s. [...] and, because of his ability to make connections between people and ideas, "the post-box of Europe”.

Similarly, the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy says of him:

[...] he was rightly referred to as “The Secretary of Learned Europe” (“le secrétaire de l’Europe savante”, Hauréau 1877, p. 177) thanks to his sprawling correspondence, which extended his network across the whole of learned Europe, to his role as translator, editor, disseminator of scientific information, and to his ability to generate research and discoveries by creating “fine questions” (de belles questions, Pascal 1658, p. 1) addressed to the foremost scholars of the time.

MacTutor writes:

It was around this time that Mersenne started to become a coordinator for all European scholars. From 1623 he began to make a careful selection of savants who met at his convent in Paris or corresponded with him from all across Europe and even from as far afield as Constantinople and Transylvania (present-day Romania). His regular visitors, or correspondents, included Peiresc, Gassendi, Descartes, Roberval, Beeckman, J B van Helmont, Fermat, Hobbes, Étienne Pascal, and his son Blaise Pascal. He set up meetings of scholars from around Europe during which they would read and review scientific papers, both national and international, exchange contacts with other scholars and plan and discuss experiments and other work. This came to be known as the Académie Parisiensis and sometimes among friends as the Académie Mersenne. It was notably one of most resourceful centres of research at that time, meeting weekly at members' houses and later in Mersenne's cell due to his weakened health. The list of Mersenne's correspondents kept increasing and Mersenne himself did not hesitate to travel to meetings with scholars all around Europe.

But surely Mersenne's role was not unique in this regard. Other people must have performed similar functions elsewhere, even if not as notably as Mersenne.
Who were Mersenne’s counterparts in this regard? Was such a role essentially a late-sixteenth/early-seventeenth century phenomenon, depending as it did on a functioning postal system or are the other historical examples.

A bit later, John Collins (1625-1683) became known for this as well, and (from Wikipedia, which cites Florian Cajoli: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1911.11997596) he was even called "English Mersenne." I also think of the Jesuits as providing something of a similar role in science dissemination, no hard source though.

Hatch in The Scientific Revolution: Correspondence Networks calls these men 'intelligencers' that "adapted the Renaissance ideal of a Republic of Letters to the realities of the New Science", and names Ismaël Boulliau, Samuel Hartlib, Fabri de Peiresc and Henry Oldenburg, aside from Collins and Mersenne. According to him, "no synthetic study of 'intelligencers' or detailed analysis of correspondence networks has been undertaken."

@SamGallagher I'm surprised that you suggest the Jesuits in this regard.  The impression  I had of them is that of the gestapo of the Catholic Church.  Well, maybe "gestapo" is a bit harsh, but surly enforcers of the anti-science attitudes of the church.

@Conifold I recognize a few of the names you mention - Oldenburg, because he was one of the founders of the Royal Society, as well as Hartlib and Collins - all, no doubt, because of my English bias.  I'm surprised that this area has not been active in historical research, it being an important subject.  I guess it's a case of too much mathematics/science and too few researchers.

Hatch's short article makes for an interesting read.  It paints a much more free-talking picture of these networks than I had previously imagined.

@nwr Are you sure you don't have the Jesuits mixed up with other orders, such as the Dominicans who were involved with the Inquisition? The Jesuits are widely considered the intellectual elite of the Catholic Church and historically have been founders of numerous schools and universities (such as Santa Clara University near where I live). The Jesuits also introduced Western mathematical and scientific knowledge to China. The Jesuit astronomer Johann Adam Schall von Bell even became an advisor to a Qing dynasty emperor.

@nwr Re " ... enforcers of the anti-science attitudes of the church" I don't see how that applies to the Jesuits. Among many others, Mersenne, Descartes, Diderot, and Buffon received their education at Jesuit colleges, and the Wikipedia article on Descartes notes: "In 1607, late because of his fragile health, he entered the Jesuit Collège Royal Henry-Le-Grand at La Flèche, where he was introduced to mathematics and physics, including Galileo's work."

@nwr yes, it is probably your English bias; a Chinese person would likely have the opposite bias. For the Chinese, the Jesuits were the great intellectuals who spread valuable scientific knowledge (foremost among them Matteo Ricci), while the English were seen as the greatest criminals in history - raiders and murderers.

@njuffa It’s my understanding that the remit of the Jesuits, just like the attitude of the church, has changed over time.  The Jesuits were originally established as a counter-reformation group. At the time of Mersenne they were led by Francis Boriga, who issued the following memorandum: “In logic, natural philosophy, ethics and metaphysics, Aristotle's doctrine is to be followed.”  He goes on to state that no one is allowed to “defend or teach anything opposed, detracting, or unfavorable to the faith, either in philosophy or theology. (continued)...

(continuation) Let no one defend anything against the axioms received by the philosophers, such as: there are only four causes, there are only four elements, there are only three principles of natural things, fire is hot and dry, air is humid and hot.  Let no one defend such propositions as that natural agents act at a distance without a medium…etc… This is not just an admonition, but a teaching we impose.”  Surely such instruction is contrary to the empirical methods gaining favor at the time.

@M.Lonardi Please see my comment to used njuffa posted above.

@nwr I always remain surprised to see how Anglo-Saxons are obsessed with Catholicism and the Jesuits; such an obsession, while understandable until a few decades ago to justify the Protestant Reformation and/or Anglicanism, nowadays, with secularization and Islamic immigration, sounds ridiculous; thus, because of this obsession, you magnify Francesco Borgia and erase Matteo Ricci, then forget that your national glory Isaac Newton did not conform to the stereotype of the scientist that you have in mind (and demand to impose on others).

Reminder: comments are not for extended discussion. To continue, Id recommend moving to a chat.

@M.Lonardi I assure you that my suspicions apply to both sides of the Protestant/Catholic divide.  It was not my intention to ignore Ricci, who taught the Thomist theology of the church.  As for my view of Newton, please see my answer here.

@nwr After seeing your post on Newton (unorthodox opinion with a downvote), I have completely changed my opinion: you are a great guy!
P.S.: "The Chronology of Ancient Kingdoms Amended" is a masterpiece that has not been understood
P.P.S.: sorry Sam, we're done
